# Matlab image processing - problems with recognizing circles

Tags: matlab, image-processing, blob, geometry

I'm writing a MATLAB program that would be able to different circles from squares. The process involves converting the image into binary form. I use an average filter of size 10 to remove noise because the pictures will all be taken with a low-res camera. I calculate the circularity of the blob as follows.

```
blobMeasurements = regionprops(BW_rotated,'Perimeter', 'Area', 'FilledArea')

perimeters = [blobMeasurements.Perimeter];
filledAreas = [blobMeasurements.FilledArea];
roundness = (4 * pi * filledAreas) ./ (perimeters .^2);
roundness = max(roundness);
```

I tried this out with a few images off the net. The roundness of a perfect circle would be 1. I used a threshold of 0.8 (which is pretty wide) to judge if the image is that of a circle. However, I do not get very good results this way. For example, using the following image:

[image: Example Image]

The circle on the left is the original image and the picture on the right is the final binary image. It should be noted that the major axis of each image is obtained beforehand and the image is rotated by that amount in order to ensure that all shapes in the image are aligned with the horizontal axis. Although the binary image appears smaller in the figure, it has only been rotated.

For this particular image I get a roundness of 0.78 which is very low considering it's unmistakably a circle. I sometimes get values of roundness of over 0.85 for images containing a square.

Could someone help me out with this? Would really appreciate any direction.

Comment: what is the green line you have at the binary mask image?

Comment: please check out the method for perimeter calculation in the tutorial mentioned in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24802605/1714410).

Comment: The green line is just a boundary I generated to enclose the shape. I did try using the method in your link, but I actually get a lower value now of 0.78 for the same circle.

Comment: The circle in the tutorial there with a roundness of 0.91 seems to be a "less-round" circle than the one I'm using, yet it gets a higher value.

Comment: have you tried running your code on the image in the tutorial? do you get the same results? there is an issue with computing area and perimeter of discrete shapes...

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I did try running the code in the tutorial with my image of a red circle. The image as it is gets a roundness of around 0.9. I get the same result with my code. But when the object is rotated to fix orientation issues, the same problem arises. I guess rotating affects the blob pixels causing the perimeter to change. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: how do you rotate your image? how do you convert the rotated image back to a binary mask?

Comment: I rotated the image after it was converted to binary. I used regionprops to obtain the orientation of the blob to the horizontal and rotated the image by the negative of that value.