# detecting specific shape using simulink

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulink, object-detection, matlab-cvst

i am using simulink to implement image processing(edge detection and hough transform) in detecting and tracking object. after i implement the model it works fine,but now i want to detect a specific object for example circle shape (ball) or any other shapes.

the blocks i used for my model are:

1. from video device
2. color space conversion
3. delay
4. subtract
5. abs
6. constant
7. matlab function
8. gaussian filter
9. edge detection
10. histogram equalization
11. logical operator
12. hough transform
13. data type conversion
14. blob analysis
15. draw shape
16. to video display

which simulink block i can use to specify the object and how to do it?

your support and help is highly appreciated and i need the solution as soon as possible..

regards

Mohammed

Comment: Change the Hough transform to a [Circular Hough transform](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfindcircles.html) so you can detect circles.  However, depending on what particular object you want to detect, you could use simply geometric and shape descriptors, or you may have to do some machine learning and train with example images.  Please give more details on the **kinds** of objects you want to detect and track.

Comment: i want to detect square shape using simulink block.. and i could not find any circular hough transform in simulink block.. can you advice if there is one

Comment: Try taking a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802059/removing-square-objects - This gives you an idea of how to detect square objects in an image.