# Image segmentation and Image Recognition - How to recognise the coordinates of a white patch in a black background image?

Tags: php, image, image-processing, image-recognition, image-segmentation

**Aim: Find the white patch with the biggest area. And if possible then confirm if it is a circle. Then find the average centre of this patch and radius.**

I have thought of creating an edge around the images, but I don't know how that would help in finding out the area of the patches.

I am trying to accomplish this and if anyone can guide me in the right direction, I would really appreciate it.

I am currently using php.gd library and that is the only tool I have.

Thanks

Comment: I don't have experience in PHP, but determining the area is very simple.  All you have to do is count how many white pixels there are for each object.  Now, to determine whether the object with the largest area is a circle or not, you can use the formula here from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24802059/removing-square-objects - The formula states that an object that is prone to be circular has a ratio close to 1 whereas non-circular objects have a ratio that is much lower.  You can set a threshold to determine whether the shape is circular or not.

Comment: @rayryeng thank you for your solution. How do you calculate the area of each object separately? Counting the white pixels will give a cumulative area for all of the objects.

Comment: I didn't say to calculate the area of **all** of the objects together - you calculate the area of each object individually. php.gd only has very basic image manipulation stuff.  What you'll have to do is perform a connected components labeling - http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/label.htm - This gives a unique label per unique object. From there, you can loop through all unique labels and find their total areas.  I have no knowledge in PHP so I don't know of any libraries that you could do this with.... but hopefully you can find something that deals with connected components and php.gd.

Comment: I think I have worked out a way. Do you know how can I create an edge around these objects. Any particular algorithm?

Comment: With what is available in php.gd, you can use any standard gradient estimation technique.  Take a look at the `imageconvolution` method in php.gd: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php - With this method, it requires a 3 x 3 convolution mask.  The 3 x 3 mask you can try using is:  `$edgeMatrix = array(1,1,1,1,-8,1,1,1,1)`.  The divisor and offset can both be 0 (`$divisor = 0; $offset = 0;`). This is a Laplacian mask that also doubles as an edge detector.

Comment: thanks buddy. can you please post these as an answer and I will accept them. Thanks

Comment: Such a shame you can't use ImageMagick - you can solve this in a single command line :-)

Comment: I can do this in imagemagick, but my preference is to write the algorithm which is customised for a very low power system. So I just wanted a just of what to do. but the problem is resolved. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detecting edges in images is actually quite simple.  The most standard way is to use an [image convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28image_processing%29#Convolution) operation and choosing the right kernel to sweep over your image.  There is a function in `php.gd` called [`imageconvolution`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imageconvolution.php) where you can specify an input image, a convolution kernel, a divisor and an offset.  The divisor simply divides all values in the kernel by this value and the offset adds a value to each value in the kernel.  As such, assuming that your image is loaded into the array `$im`, you would do this:

```
$edgeMatrix = array(-1,-1,-1,-1,8,-1,-1,-1,-1);
$divisor = 0;
$offset = 0;

imageconvolution($im, $edgeMatrix, $divisor, $offset);
```

Note that `imageconvolution` mutates the original input image, so `$im` will contain the edge detected result.  Make sure that you have a copy of the original image somewhere in case you need it.

`$edgeMatrix = array(-1,-1,-1,-1,8,-1,-1,-1,-1);` is the standard [Laplacian convolution matrix](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/log.htm) and is used quite often for edge detection tasks.

However, there is a function called [`imagefilter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilter.php) where there is an edge detect flag - `IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT`.  This function filters an image given one of several options, and edge detection is one of these options.  As such, you would do this:

```
imagefilter($im, IMG_FILTER_EDGEDETECT);
```

As with `imageconvolution`, `imagefilter` also mutates the input image, so again make sure that you keep the original image somewhere if you need it.

Hopefully one of these will work for you!