# How to calculate the value of the 'roundness shape feature' of an image contour?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I am doing an assignment on Image classification with different shape features.

How do we compute the value for roundness of an image contour in MATLAB?

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard that can determine how "round" a contour is, or any shape in general.  However, one heuristic that I have seen is from this post by [Shai Bagon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24802605/3250829.

The heuristic is defined as:

```
ratio = 4 * pi * Area / ( Perimeter^2 )
```

`Area` is the area defined by the shape, or the total number of pixels that occupy the internal shape of the contour, and `Perimeter` is the total number of pixels that define the perimeter of the contour.

If the contour is round, the ratio is quite high.  However, if the contour is not round, the ratio is low.  Therefore, for each contour, perhaps use the above criteria as a starting point.